# how to check if a list of numbers is between 2 values in python?

Tags: python, list, compare

I have a list of numbers and I need to sort it out to know if there are any numbers of this list between 2 values (in my case between 1,50 and 2,50)

ex:

```
list_numbers = ['3,25', '3,15', '1,78', '2,10', '1,06', '1,58', '1,88', '1,19', '4,00', '2,45', '2,25', '3,00', '2,95', '2,45', '2,30', '1,52', '1,96', '6,50', '4,20', '1,27']
```

I've tried the following code but got an error: "TypeError: unorderable types: str() <= list()"

```
if '1,50' <= list_numbers <= '2,50':
            print('number between the range!')
```

EDIT: the right numbers between the 2 values will need to be stored under a variable "found" to be accessible later

Comment: List comprehension is one option: `found = [x for x in my_list if 1,5 <= float(x) <= 2,5]`

Comment: Hi, do you need to check if there are numbers in the interval [1.50, 2.50], or if there are any element between the position of elements '1,50' and '2,50'?

Comment: in the interval, and then add those numbers to a variable called "found"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use filter to get a list but first you should change it value to float and in addition don't use list as variable name. list is a built-in operation you need and shouldn't be overridden can cause some bad side effects:

```
list_ = ['3,25', '3,15', '1,78', '2,10', '1,06', '1,58', '1,88', '1,19', '4,00', '2,45', '2,25', '3,00', '2,95', '2,45', '2,30', '1,52', '1,96', '6,50', '4,20', '1,27']

list_number = [float(number.replace(",",".")) for number in list_]    
found = filter(lambda x: 1.50 <= x <= 2.50, list_number)

for value in found:
    print(value)
```

But of course if you don't want to cast it to float you can do the following as well without a problem:

```
found = filter(lambda x: "1,50" <= x <= "2,50", list_)
```

The output will be the same. (except in one it has "," and ending zero and the other result use "." without ending zeros)

Output:

```
1.78
2.1
1.58
1.88
2.45
2.25
2.45
2.3
1.52
1.96
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you want to do, you could use a for loop

```py
for value in list:
    if '1,50' <= value <= '2,50':
        print('number between the range!')
        break
```

I've added a break as I wasn't sure if you wanted to print only once or for every such number. I would also suggest you store the numbers as well, numbers, or at least, cast them when doing a comparison so you're not relying on lexographical values. E.g.:

```py
for value in list:
    if 1,50 <= float(value) <= 2,50:
        print('number between the range!')
        break
```

---

Based on your edit you'd likely want to do (if you're using a "raw" loop)

```py
found = []
for value in list:
    if 1,50 <= float(value) <= 2,50:
        found += value
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is first: Please don't use list as variable since it is built-in type offered by python. By using list as variable you are overriding it's reference to built-in type list

Second: Recommended to convert numeric strings to float or int for arithmetic operations or expressions

```
values = ['3,25', '3,15', '1,78', '2,10', '1,06', '1,58', '1,88', '1,19', '4,00', '2,45', '2,25', '3,00', '2,95', '2,45', '2,30', '1,52', '1,96', '6,50', '4,20', '1,27']
found = [i for i in map(lambda n: float(n.replace(',', '.')), values) if 1.50 < i < 2.50]

for i in found:
   print(i)
```

Output:

```
1.78
2.1
1.58
1.88
2.45
2.25
2.45
2.3
1.52
1.96
```

Comment: "To use arithmetic operations values must be of numbers (integers or floats)". This isn't, in fact, true. Python will happily compare strings based on their value, character by character. Take for example `'1,50' <= '2'`, this expression will evaluate to `True`.

Comment: @kopecs Thanks +1 for noticing. For arithmetic operations it has to be either int or float. Strings can be used in conditional expressions. Python does comparison of strings using it's encoding(ASCII) code points Ex: '/' < '0'  evals True,  '9' < ':' evaluates True. Yet, numeric string comparison works well since python does comparison char by char

Comment: I'm not sure that Python necessitates ASCII (if anything I would assume its UTF-8), but as far as I'm aware 0-9 are always in a nice contiguous block*, so as long as the number of leading digits (i.e. before decimal sep.) are the same I think this is actually fairly portable---especially as it isn't locale dependent like calling `float` is.

* except for perhaps some arcane dialect of EBCDIC

Comment: Here is simple example why string comparison won't work  as expected for numeric strings:  '9' < '10' evals False,  '99.0' == '99'  evals False, '99.9' < '100.0' evals False, '99,9' < '100,0' evals False .  String comparison is not always ideal for numeric strings

Comment: Like I said, assuming the same number of leading digits it'll work---if you break that precondition, the result obviously won't follow :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for elem in list:
  if '1,50' <= elem <= '2,50':
    print(True)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, all of the strings in the **list** are in a wrong format. Python will cast the exception when trying to parse the strings to a number:

> (***ValueError***: could not convert string to float: '3,25')

This is because there's a **comma** (",") and not a **peroid** (".") in the strings. You need to replace all of the commas with the peroids before casting them to the specific datatype. Example below...

```
# Bad name, use something else as "list" is a built-in type    
list = ['3,25', '3,15', '1,78', '2,10', '1,06', '1,58', '1,88', '1,19', '4,00', '2,45', '2,25', '3,00', '2,95', '2,45', '2,30', '1,52', '1,96', '6,50', '4,20', '1,27']

# The numbers to extract from the list of strings
numbers = []

# For each number (as string), reformat the string and then cast it to a floating number 
for number_str in list:
   number = float(number_str.replace(',', '.'))
   numbers.append(number)
```

You could then check if there's numbers the **min** and **max** value:

```
for n in numbers:
   if 1.50 <= n <= 2.50:
      print("{} is between 1.50 and 2.50".format(n))
      break
```

---

***Edit:***

As @kopecs said, **float** is actually *local dependent*, which means that the seperator can be changed to whatever symbol you want. See:
[locale — Internationalization services](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html)

Comment: he never cast the strings into number.

Comment: This is locale dependent. `float` cares about the value of `locale.localeconv()['decimal_point']`.

Comment: Thanks for the input @kopecs! I had totally forgot about that.